# How to check if a pymongo cursor has query results

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

I need to check if a `find` statement returns a non-empty query.

What I was doing was the following:

```
query = collection.find({"string": field})
if not query: #do something
```

Then I realized that my `if` statement was never executed because `find` returns a cursor, either the query is empty or not.

Therefore I checked the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) and I find two methods that can help me:

1. `count(with_limit_and_skip=False)` which (from the description):

   > Returns the number of documents in the results set for this query.

   It seems a good way to check, but this means that I need to count
   all the results in cursor to know if it is zero or not, right? A little bit expensive?
2. `retrieved` which (from the description):

   > The number of documents retrieved so far.

   I tested it on an empty query set and it returns zero, but it's not
   clear what it does and I don't know if it's right for me.

So, which is the best way (best practice) to check if a `find()` query returns an empty set or not? Is one of the methods described above right for this purpose? And what about performance? Are there other ways to do it?

---

Just to be clear: I need to know if the query is empty and I'd like to find the best way with the cursor with respect to performance and being pythonic.

Comment: That depends on what you wanna do with it

Comment: @VincentBeltman I just need to know if the query returns something using that cursor.

Comment: You're already performing the query in your collection.find() method anyway. The "count" method is just returning the number of documents that the find method returned to the cursor.  You would just do "if query.count > 0:"

Comment: @vintastic I understood that, but how about performance? Does `count` need to rescan all results found to give me a number?

Comment: @boh the cursor is a pointer to the result set of the query. So a rescan would be unnecessary.

Comment: @vintastic So the cursor "knows" how many objects have been found by the query?

Comment: If your further workflow supposes using of a list, you can extract cursor data with: `lst = list(query)` and **then** check `if not lst: #do something`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**EDIT**: *While this was true in 2014, modern versions of pymongo and MongoDB have changed this behaviour. Buyer beware:*

`.count()` is the correct way to find the number of results that are returned in the query. The `count()` method does not exhaust the iterator for your cursor, so you can safely do a `.count()` check before iterating over the items in the result set.

Performance of the count method was greatly improved in MongoDB 2.4. The only thing that could slow down your `count` is if the query has an index set on it, or not. To find out if you have an index on the query, you can do something like

```
query = collection.find({"string": field})
print query.explain()
```

If you see `BasicCursor` in the result, you need an index on your `string` field for this query.

---

**EDIT**: as @alvapan pointed out, [pymongo deprecated this](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/changelog.html#changes-in-version-3-7-0) method in pymongo 3.7+ and now prefers you to use `count_documents` in a separate query.

```
item_count = collection.count_documents({"string": field})
```

The right way to count the number of items you've returned on a query is to check the `.retreived` counter on the query after you iterate over it, or to `enumerate`the query in the first place:

```
# Using .retrieved
query = collection.find({"string": field})
for item in query:
    print(item)

print('Located {0:,} item(s)'.format(query.retrieved))
```

Or, another way:

```
# Using the built-in enumerate
query = collection.find({"string": field})
for index, item in enumerate(query):
    print(item)

print('Located {0:,} item(s)'.format(index+1))
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up mate. .count() is the perfect function to check non-empty query. I was having similar problem and was resolved with this function.

Comment: @VooDooNOFX, PyMongo 3.7 has deprecated cursor.count(), and ask us to use collection.count_documents() instead. Then I don't know what will be the new *corrrect* way to find the number of results that are returned in the cursor. Do we need to `collection.count_documents(query_string)` first, check the number, then `collection.find(query_string)` to get the real results? But the new way requires us to do query twice, while the old way does only once, which seems better.

Comment: @AlvaPan edited the response, Thanks. Personally, I prefer to just perform the query, then count the documents afterwards. Not many scalable solutions should be using a count method to know ahead of time how many documents they're querying, except maybe a total document count in the collection use-case.

Answer (score 15):

How about just using `find_one` instead of `find` ? Then you can just check whether you got a result or `None`. And if "string" is indexed, you can pass `fields = {"string":1, "_id" :0}`, and thus make it an index-only query, which is even faster.

Comment: The field `string` is indexed, but I can't use `findOne` because it is not guaranteed that there is only one result (actually it's unlikely that there's one).

Comment: In my understanding, all you want to know is whether you have any results for the query or not, is that correct ? If that is the case, find_one is enough for your case: if it returns a value, it means that find() would have found at least one result, and if it returns `None` it means that find() would return 0 results.

Comment: Yes, but if there are no results, I'll do something, else I'll do something with results, tipycally showing all of them. Do you say that is more efficient doing a query with `findOne` on an indexed field and if it's not empty perform again the query with `find`?

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't understand from your question that you need the results. The answer really depends of a few factors, like whether you expect most of your queries to return results or not (if not - find_one can work well), and whether your query uses an index (and then count() is fast).

Comment: Another option: just iterate over the results and do your thing. If there are no results, it will be an empty loop, and you can detect it using a flag in your code (set the flag to True inside the loop).

Comment: seems line find is a lot faster than find_one. see: https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/

Answer (score 13):

Another solution is converting cursor to list, if the cursor doesn't have any data then empty list else list contains all data.

```
 doc_list = collection.find({}); #find all data
 have_list = True if len(list(doc_list)) else False;
```

Comment: I prefer this also, but disadvantage of this way is that list() function will exhaust cursor fully. Better to use it, when you are sure that your cursor contains relatively small amount of documents.

Comment: list does exhaust, consider `doc_list = list(collection.find({}));` where no results returns an empty list `[]` and works in Python with `if not doc_list:` and `len(doc_list)`

Answer (score 4):

From my tests, the quickest way is

```
if query.first():
    # do something

In [51]: %timeit query = MyMongoDoc.objects(); query.first()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.12 ms per loop

In [52]: %timeit query = MyMongoDoc.objects(); query.count()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.28 ms per loop
```

(Using MongoDB 2.6.7, 2015-03-26)

Answer (score 0):

I end up using simple counter, since i don't want calling server twice for no reason:

```py
cursor = someCollection.find( query )

ct = 0

for doc in cursor:

    ct += 1

    # some code

if ct == 0:
    
    # cursor was empty
```

Comment: There is no need for this. `cursor.retrieved` gives you the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cursor.retrieved](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.retrieved). However, as the name suggests this only works *after* you have iterated the cursor, not before: if you call `cursor.retrieved` before iterating the cursor, it will return 0 even if the query has matching documents.

So `retrieved` needs to be used according to the following general pattern:

```py
cursor = collection.find(…)

for doc in cursor:
    process(doc)

if cursor.retrieved == 0:
    handle("no matching documents found")
```

Alternative suggestions in other answers have one of three disadvantages:

- Either they convert the cursor into a list, causing the entire result set to be copied into memory.
- Or they peek at the first result document, which means having to duplicate the processing logic.
- Or they perform a redundant query to the database via `count_documents` or similar.